# Single LiveData observe for multiple API calls

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I just wanted to know and how to implement ***multiple API call observer in a single view(Act or Fragment)***

So my question brief is I have a **multiple API's calls** in a single Activity like fetch *user detail, fetch banner image list and products list* via **ViewModel** and **Livedata**,

So is it compulsory to observe **three livedata** depend on **three API** calls?

I want to observe only a single livedata for three different APIs.

like below example, I have three live data for three APIs

```
var userLiveData = MutableLiveData<UserDetails>()
var bannerLiveData = MutableLiveData<BannerDetails>()
var productLiveData = MutableLiveData<Product>()
```

Call rest API and observe in Act like below

```
userLiveData.observe(this, Observer { data ->

})
bannerLiveData.observe(this, Observer { data ->

})
productLiveData.observe(this, Observer { data ->

})
```

it is ok no issue but I think it is not good practice to observe every API call, I need to combine all three API calls to one so is there any solution for that?

I read about **MediatorLiveData** but cant help!
Forgive me for my bad English.

If anyone knows anything please help me.

Comment: If your APIs can return the same type of response or you can caste them into the same type of response then it can be possible.

Comment: If you use same livedata at multiple locations then, how will you identify which API got called?

Comment: what you tried using "MediatorLiveData".I think u achieve ur goal with the help of "MediatorLiveData".If not explain what u tried and then it will increase the chance of getting usefull answers

Comment: are you using RxJava/RxKotlin by any chance? You can use zip operator to get all the call result and then post the values to your livedata.

Comment: Did you got any solution to this..

Comment: @HarrySharma I manage with API call generic and observer one live data for All Api call and after cast with particular type.

Comment: Can you please post some code for this.. How you passed Response model for API call then

Comment: use sealed class in kotlin